# v-autocomplete not showing all options when data under item-value tag is same

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

i need to print the tag value of selected options and i am using v-autocomplete.

```
<v-autocomplete
  label="Trade-as Entity"
  v-model="tradingAs"
  :items="getTradeEntities"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="entity"
  clearable
  hide-details
  change="tradeChange"
/>
```

If I put 'tag' in place of id in item-value, i won't be able to see all the output values. as tag can be same for Two options in database. My main objective is to get tag data When i print tradingAs variable. But from this code i am getting only id of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [return-object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-return-object) prop - then your model will contain the whole Object of the selected option and you can easily access the Tag or any other attribute.